# I accidently deleted my package.json file and node modules

Tags: node.js, json, node-modules, npm-install, npm-init

I accidentally deleted my **`package.json`** file and **node modules** and now I'm unable to get JSON file I've changed the directory and started fresh also but it didn't work.

[image]

I have tried deleting the npm-cache and try to start with a new directory but didn't work
I have tried various commands :

- `rm -rf npm-cache`
- `npm cache clean --force`

Answer (score 0):

You will have to try with:

```bash
npm init
```

Or:

```bash
npm init -y
```

To initialise your project and then add your dependencies using:

```bash
npm install <package name>
```

To populate your `package.json` file.